# Sql server stored Procedure for cut records by comparing between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two tables i should make a comparing between those two tables, the first table have one column this column is the full `URL` and the other table have two columns first column is `URLCategory` and the other one is `the number` of how many `/` i should cut before in the other table column `URL`

the first table is

```
                          URL
http://10.6.2.26/ERP/HRServices/WorkflowService.asmx
http://195.170.180.170/SADAD/PaymentNotificationService.asmx
http://10.6.2.26/ERP/HRServices/WorkflowService.asmx
http://10.6.2.26/ERP/HRServices/WorkflowService.asmx
http://10.6.2.26/ERP/HRServices/WorkflowService.asmx
http://217.146.8.6/din.aspx?s=11575802&client=DynGate&p=10002926
http://195.170.180.170/SADAD/PaymentNotificationService.asmx
http://10.6.2.26/ERP/HRServices/WorkflowService.asmx
http://195.170.180.170/SADAD/PaymentNotificationService.asmx
http://www.google.com/
```

the Second table which is hould compare with

```
  URL                              CUT_BEFORE
http://10.6.2.26                  3
http://217.146.8.6                1
http://195.170.180.170            2
```

I should compare between second table with first column to be like that

```
  URL                        
http://10.6.2.26/ERP/HRServices
http://195.170.180.170/SADAD
http://10.6.2.26/ERP/HRServices
http://10.6.2.26/ERP/HRServices
http://10.6.2.26/ERP/HRServices
http://217.146.8.6
http://195.170.180.170/SADAD
http://10.6.2.26/ERP/HRServices
http://195.170.180.170/SADAD
http://www.google.com/
```

What's the procedure script with while loop to do  something like that in SQLServer

waiting for your answers

Thanks

Comment: @OP: Is `MySQL` tag irrelevant then?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the code below.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @URL TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), URL VARCHAR(200))

INSERT INTO @URL VALUES
('http://10.6.2.26/ERP/HRServices/WorkflowService.asmx'),
('http://195.170.180.170/SADAD/PaymentNotificationService.asmx'),
('http://10.6.2.26/ERP/HRServices/WorkflowService.asmx'),
('http://10.6.2.26/ERP/HRServices/WorkflowService.asmx'),
('http://10.6.2.26/ERP/HRServices/WorkflowService.asmx'),
('http://217.146.8.6/din.aspx?s=11575802&client=DynGate&p=10002926'),
('http://195.170.180.170/SADAD/PaymentNotificationService.asmx'),
('http://10.6.2.26/ERP/HRServices/WorkflowService.asmx'),
('http://195.170.180.170/SADAD/PaymentNotificationService.asmx'),
('http://www.google.com/')

DECLARE @MAP TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), URL VARCHAR(200),CUT INT)
INSERT INTO @MAP VALUES
('http://10.6.2.26',3),
('http://217.146.8.6',1),  
('http://195.170.180.170',2)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

See the code from here

```
DECLARE @DEST TABLE 
(ID INT, URL VARCHAR(200),URLREF VARCHAR(200),CUT INT,RESULT VARCHAR(200))
INSERT  INTO @DEST (ID,URL,URLREF,CUT)
SELECT  A.ID,A.URL,B.URL URLREF,B.CUT
FROM    @URL A,@MAP B   
WHERE   LEFT(A.URL,LEN(B.URL)) = B.URL

DECLARE     @A INT = 1,
            @B INT,
            @C VARCHAR(200),
            @D VARCHAR(200),
            @E INT,
            @F INT,
            @G INT,
            @H VARCHAR(200)

SET     @B = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @DEST)

WHILE @A<= @B
BEGIN
    SET @C = (  SELECT SUBSTRING(URL,LEN(URLREF)+2,LEN(URL)) 
                FROM @DEST WHERE ID = @A)

    SET @H = ''
    SET @G = 0
    SET @F = 1
    SET @E = LEN(@C)
    WHILE @F <= @E
        BEGIN
            SET @D = SUBSTRING(@C,@F,1)
            IF @D = '/'
                BEGIN
                SET @G = @G + 1
                IF @G = (SELECT CUT-1 FROM @DEST WHERE ID = @A)
                    BEGIN
                    SET @F = @E
                    END
                END
        SET @H = @H + @D
        SET @F = @F + 1
        END

        UPDATE @DEST 
        SET RESULT = URLREF +'/'+ LEFT(@H,LEN(@H)-1) 
        WHERE ID = @A
SET @A = @A + 1
END

UPDATE  @DEST
SET     RESULT = URLREF
WHERE   CUT = 1

SELECT RESULT FROM @DEST
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Added comment:**
If We use the above two set of code in an SSMS window, we wont get an error.
I tried it with empty values in both @URL and @MAP. Still I am not getting error.
If you are making it to varchar(max), please make sure that you make changes everywhere..

Comment: HI BRO thank uso much for ur help but when i make the insertation in the logical table by select statment it's give me error: `Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.` even i make the data type in the `parameters` `varchar(max)` because i working now with my real data what i should do with this error shal we make it as procedure or what we should do http://stackoverflow.com/users/3265371/jithin